# Filling Vector from NodeList

Tags: java, vector, nodelist

I am trying to fill a String Vector by data from a NodeList (which values is String too), but it doesn't work and Vector is still empty.
What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

```
Document doc = parseFile(xml);
Vector <String> x = new Vector <>();
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("Stuff");
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        x.addElement(list.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }

public Document parseFile(File file) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = (Document) builder.parse(file);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: you need to post more code

Comment: "NodeList list" must be empty

Comment: @Alex but how will I fiil it from an empty list?

Comment: do you confirm ?  does "doc.getElementsByTagName("Stuff");" return an empty list ?  If so, there is no way for us to give you the answer. "list" comes from "doc", "doc" comes from "parseFile(xml)" and we don't have the code

Comment: @AsteriskNinja I've added a parsing method, what else will be helpful?

Comment: If anybody is to help here, it’s time for a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you very much, sir

Answer (score 1):

Made mistake in tag name in NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("Stuff");

Looking for wrong "Stuff" :)

Sorry, thank you all for help anyway